# $resolve not added to $scope until after controller creation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-routing

I'm trying to take advantage of the (new in 1.5.0) feature that [adds the resolve map to the scope of the route](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/docs/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider).  However, it seems like the map isn't actually getting added to the scope until after the controller has loaded.

Here's a very simple module that demonstrates the issue (from this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/HzR1YA)):

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
  function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider.otherwise({
      controller: "editController",
      controllerAs: "ec",
      templateUrl: "edit.html",
      resolve: {
        resolveData: function() {
          return {
            foo: "bar",
            blah: "halb"
          }
        }
      }

    });
  }
]);

app.controller("editController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
  // undefined
  console.log($scope.$resolve);
  setTimeout(function() {
    // the object is there, including $scope.$resolve.resolveData
    console.log($scope.$resolve);
  }, 0)
}]);
```

If you watch the console, you'll note that `$scope.$resolve` is `undefined` when the controller is created. However, it's there immediately afterwards, as demonstrated by the `setTimeout`.

I can't find anything in the documentation that suggests this should be the case.  Is this a bug?  Or am I just not getting something fundamental about how angular works?

Answer (score 0):

Notice your object is much bigger than you expect, and actually your object is on `$resolve`. This is mostly [explained in the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider), however, could be more elaborate with examples...

> the resolve map will be available on the scope of the route, under
>   $resolve

No need to dig into this, when you `resolve`, the named object becomes an injectable you can then place on `$scope`, in this case, `resolveData`. Observe the following...

```
app.controller('editController', ['$scope', 'resolveData', function($scope, resolveData) {
  console.log(resolveData);
  // -- $scope.data = resolveData; // -- assign it here
}]);
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HuS2jHj9tmXwjeNUhB3A?p=preview) - updated demo

---

Investigation of why you are getting `undefined` is due to the nature of awaiting digest cycles in the framework. An acceptable workaround to get a handle on `$resolve` would include injecting and wrapping the call in a `$timeout`, which forces a digest cycle in which your object will be available in the asynchronous callback. If this approach is not ideal, forego injecting `$timeout` and either call `$route.current.locals` directly for your resolved object, or inject your object as a named parameter of which it will have resolved immediately as the example above demonstrates.

Comment: Right.  the resolve map is supposed to be in $scope.$resolve.  And it is, but only AFTER the controller is finished being created.

Comment: It is actually there. Log out just `$scope` without the timeout and check out that object

Comment: No, it's not.  It looks like it is if you `console.dir($scope)`, because it's there by the time you can actually click on it in the console, but $resolve isn't actually added to $scope until after the controller is loaded.

Comment: Well, it's doesn't seem to be documented why this is happening. Is there a reason why are you not calling it as an injectable anyways?

Comment: My guess is a bug, the docs do state it will wait for a promise to resolve and even forced as a promise it is not working see [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1k9okhicN83qHajReqP9?p=preview)

Comment: It actually waits for the promise just fine.  I cut that out of my question because it doesn't matter if you use a promise in your resolve map or not - this still happens.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean it waits for it just fine if `$resolve` is still `undefined`. The docs state it will await controller instantiation if the resolve returns a promise. This is probably something to open up on github if you want a truly detailed explanation perhaps from someone who has knowledge that's been left out of the docs. I suspect this is unintentional behavior. However, there have been widely accepted answers throughout the evolution of this framework that simply states wrapping your call in a `$timeout`. I could see this being one of those as well - who knows, not me ;)

Comment: As to why I'm not just injecting it, I don't recall precisely, but I couldn't get that to work.  I thought 1.5.0 would fix that, and then I ran into this.

Comment: no worries, have you tried injecting it? That'll likely be the way you want to go anyways. That was a pretty typical pattern with ui-router, and the api here is similar so I'd imagine that's still the best practice

Comment: Aha.  Looks like this got brought up on github and was closed as "working as intended."  https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/13844  Luckily injecting it is working now.  No idea why it wasn't before.

Comment: Exactly what I suspected. Would you be willing to accept this answer based on the inject pattern? I'll edit with your comments for succinctness

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else comes across this - it was already [reported on the angular github and resolved as intended behavior](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/13844). $scope.$resolve isn't really meant to be used in controllers.  You are supposed to inject it, or use $route.current.locals.

(Or you can wrap the code using $scope.$resolve in a $timeout.)